# How to apply query variable to whereHas closure?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a query stored in a variable.

how to apply this variable to whereHas closure?

```php
$productQuery = ...; // complex query comes from another class

return CategoryModel::whereHas('products', function ($query) use($productQuery) {
    $query->apply($productQuery) // I need to apply product query here but Laravel has not this method
})->get();
```

Comment: add the complete query

Comment: Hi @Sohel0415 $productQuery is a complex query that constructed by 10 classes. It's not a simple `where` query.

Comment: Laravel doesn't have an `apply` method, but since we don't know what your `$productQuery` looks like, it's going to be difficult to give you any directions. You could deconstruct your complex query into RAW queries as Laravel does support Raw Methods. More on https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Comment: @Rezrazi I didn't understand why you need to know about `$productQuery' for simplified you can imagine `$productQuery = Product::where('activated', true)` and I don't want to write this query in whereHas closure. I mean I want to use `$productQuery' instead of rewrite that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [searching to Laravel QueryBuilder class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.php#L794) I found the method `mergeConstraintsFrom` and by this method I could reuse my query in a `whereHas` closure. The final code is:

```php
$productQuery = ...; // complex query comes from another class

return CategoryModel::whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($productQuery) {
    $query->mergeConstraintsFrom($productQuery);
})->get();
```